# Cakephp Plugin prefix not working

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, prefix

I'm creating a Cakephp(3.5.14) plugin, it is working fine with the below given routes
plugins/timesheet/config/routes.php

```
Router::plugin(
        'Timesheet', ['path' => '/timesheets'], function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Timesheets', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/edit', ['controller' => 'Timesheets', 'action' => 'edit']);
    $routes->connect('/add', ['controller' => 'Timesheets', 'action' => 'add']);

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
```

as per the documentation [this](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-routes) I added in 
project src/config/routes.php

```
$routes->scope('/backend', function ($routes) {
        $routes->loadPlugin('Timesheet');
    });
```

BUt somehow, it's not working.

My URL: www.xxx.com/backend/timesheets

Error: BackendController could not be found.

In the case you tried to access a plugin controller make sure you added it to your composer file or you use the autoload option for the plugin.

Error: Create the class BackendController below in file: src\Controller\BackendController.php

use App\Controller\AppController;

class BackendController extends AppController
{

}

**Stack Trace:**

```
⟩ Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->missingController
CORE\src\Http\ControllerFactory.php, line 38
⟩ Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->create
CORE\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php, line 90
⟩ Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch
CORE\src\Http\BaseApplication.php, line 108
⟩ Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke
CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php, line 104
⟩ Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke
CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php, line 88
⟩ Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke
CORE\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php, line 98
⟩ Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke
ROOT\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware.php, line 52
⟩ DebugKit\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware->__invoke
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 51
⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->run
CORE\src\Http\Server.php, line 81
⟩ Cake\Http\Server->run
ROOT\webroot\index.php, line 40
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the other routes that are connected in your application, there's most likely a route connected earlier that catches the request, probably one that looks for something like `/:controller/:action` (either explicitly, or as fallback routes), hence it uses the `backend` part as the controller.

You can easily get a list of all connected routes via the [**routes shell**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/routes-shell.html):

```
bin/cake routes
```